# Как составить Constraint Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

Уже 2 часа не могу понять что делаю не так...

Вот мой `ConstraintLayout`

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
android:id="@+id/ll_search_passengers_family_members_header"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/Seashell"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/large_space"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/large_space">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    style="@style/Text_16sp.MidnightBlueTwo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:text="@string/add_passengers_from_family_account"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_search_passengers_number_indicator"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_search_passengers_number_indicator"
    style="@style/Text_12sp.FloatingLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/space_1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="@dimen/space_1dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_search_passengers_expand_family"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_search_passengers_expand_family"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@mipmap/search_open_plus"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

Вот хочу, чтоб было так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге получаю вот такой результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текст заваливается влево за границу экрана, номер залазит на текст... Не пойму почему текст просто не опускается на вторую строку?

Уже пробовал сделать тоже самое с `LinnearLayout` и `RelativeLayout` и все равно проблема в том, что текст не хочет спускаться на вторую строку и постоянно либо залазит на что-то  либо уходит за границу экрана

Что делаю не так?

Comment: Наверное дело в ширине `wrap_content`. Не знаю как для констраинта сработает, но для LinearLayout может либо `match_parent` сработать или проставление веса с 0 ширины. Наверняка аналог и для костраинта есть

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Я пробовал, не срабатывает... Мне нужно, чтоб вью `number indicator` TextView была сразу после TextView если задать веса для всех вью в `LinnearLayout` допустим 70 для TextView 10 для индикатора и 20 для `+` то вроде как все более менее до тех пор пока длина текста не уменьшается в 2 раза(так как работаю с несколькими языками) и получается что сначала текст и через километр номер стоит... В общем тоже криво... Пробовал текст с номером положить в отдельный `Layout` но тоже не выходит

Answer (score 1):

Если цель - расположить иконку плюсика прижатой к правому углу, а текст первого текстового поля расширять вплоть до второго, при этом перенося текст на следующую строку, если его слишком много, но при этом прижимая второе поле к первому, то можно с помощью другой гугловой либы это сделать как-то так:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   >

        <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:flexWrap="nowrap"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/first"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/second"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_flexShrink="0"
                />
        </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>

    <ImageView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

Здесь используется либа [FlexboxLayout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout), где её `FlexboxLayout` задано `app:flexWrap="nowrap"`, первому её ребёнку ширина и высота по содержимому, а второму - добавлено `app:layout_flexShrink="0"` для того, чтобы оно не сжималось, если первый элемент хочет слишком много места.

Comment: В итоге у меня получилось это сделать с помощью `guideLine` которая в `ConstraintLayout` , но либа которую вы предложили интересная не слышал о ней. Спасибо